# Prevent queries that affect a certain number of rows

Tags: sql, ssms

Is there a setting in SSMS that prevents users from running queries that affect over a certain number of rows? Even if it doesn't prevent it, is there a way to have a notification pop-up that asks if you're "sure you want to run this query?"?

Comment: Short answer - no.

Comment: No. Think about it - how is it possible to know how many rows will be affected by the query unless you actually execute the query?? And why do you want to do such a thing, anyway? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @ADyson The problem I'm trying to solve is an accidental update of a lot of data. And I would think the setting--should it exist--would run a preliminary `select` query before the actual query to see how many rows will be affected.

Comment: Do the update. Check no of rows affected. If many, ask and then commit or rollback, depending on the answer.

Comment: @athomas you can wrap the query in a transaction, and immediately roll it back. If you're happy with what the result would be, then run it and commit the transaction instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a trigger and have temporary view as metadata to refer but again i am unaware of ssms as you tagged sql also

```
  Create view xyz as select * from table


    Create Trigger sample before 
     Update on table 
     As 
     samplecount varchar2(20), 
     samplecount1 varchar2(20);
     samplecount=Select count(*) from 
     table;
     Update xyz set........ ;
     samplecount1=Select count(*) from 
      xyz ;
     Iif(samplecount1=samplecount)
      Then...
    Else... End

    End
```

Here, above if there is any new insert then the above will work else replace select count(*)..... with

```
       select sum(case when
somebeforupdateid=someafterupdateid
       then 
        When somebeforeupdatecolumn=
         newupdatecolumn then 1 else 0 
         end 
         end) and then check totalcount- 
         sum() = oldcount
```